# Laravel Button Actions

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Working in a Lavarel App 4.2 app and I have a function in my controller and a button in my view that I want to fire off when a button is clicked in my app.

I'm not sure that I'm writing this the correct way so I figured I'd ask someone that knew more about Laravel than I do at this point.

```
  {{ Form::submit('Ok, Finalize the Records', ['class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-submit pull-right', 'action' => 'SectionController@update'])}}
```

Is this the correct way to write this? Basically I want it to update my database field form a 0 to a 1 which I have a function for that below. I'd also like to have some alert box or message that says it's fired off, but that isn't important.

```
public function update($id)
{
    $finalize = DB::table('AcademicAffairsOperations.gen_ed_assessment.courses')
        ->where('id' , $data_records2)
        ->update(['locked' => 1]);
}
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do it without $id parameter, right ?

With resource controller, you can view route list by artisan command **php artisan route:list**

```
{!! Form::model($user, array('route' => array('anything.update', $id))) !!}
{!! Form::submit('Ok, Finalize the Records', ['class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-submit pull-right']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

If you dont want use resource controller, you can replace route with action

```
{!! Form::model($user, array('route' => array('SectionController@update', $id), 'method' => 'post/put/delete...')) !!}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using the Homecontroller to call the action here. Nothing seems to happen with the coding in your example so I think I might be missing something, not sure. I think I might be able to do it without the $id, Ive been trying to teach myself Laravel 4.2 as I go here.